# Manually remove old DC server

Tags: active-directory

I have a win 2003 DC that has failed and i'm trying to clean up the metadata using ntdsutil as per instructions from http://www.petri.co.il/delete_failed_dcs_from_ad.htm and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216498

At the "remove selected server" step i get the following error

> DsRemoveDsServerW error 0x5(Access is denied.)

Any advice on how to proceed. This is a Win2008 r2 box and of course i'm logged on with full access Rights. All PC clients can log on successfully and dcdiag shows no errors except for failed replications to this non-existing DC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here, they seem to have it figured out:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverDS/thread/f3b2f13e-76b8-4155-ad6a-f9463f3e379b/

Comment: After toggling "Protect this object from accidental deletion" i was able to using the ntdsutil to remove

Comment: @Khalid Rahaman - Glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You posted that you have full access Rights, but are you a member of the Enterprise Admin group?  During a demotion, I ran into a few issues because at the time, I was only a Domain Admin.  Once added to the Enterprise Admin group, I was able to complete the demotion.

Comment: Yes, i am an "Enterprise Admin"

Answer (score 0):

Under AD Sites and Services, go to the NTDS folder of the server.  Look at the properties.  Under the Object tab, make sure "Protect object from accidental deletion" is unchecked.